# How many ways can $32$ cards be distributed so that three players receive $10$ cards each?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A card deck consists of 32 cards. Three players play together and get 10 cards each. The remaining cards form the extra deck, used during the game.
How many distributions of the deck exist?

my answer: $$\binom{32}{10} \binom{22}{10} \binom{12}{10} \binom{2}{2}$$

but the answer is very big, am i missing something here? any hints? thanks

Comment: The answer should be very big.

Comment: This game is weird (and probably doesn't exist?), since the extra deck only has 2 cards!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. If you like it, you can instead use the multinomial coefficient

$\dbinom{32}{10,10,10,2}$